# Зависимости .Net Core

Tags: visual-studio-2017, .net-core

Имеется Net Core 2.0 проект с некоторыми зависимостями, пакеты которых я устанавливал с помощью NuGet. Так вот. В случае, когда я работал с Net Framework, все зависимости в виде dll-ок складировались в выходной каталог, и мне было достаточно перетащить все выходные файлы туда, куда мне надо, и все продолжало работать. Зависимости же Net Core, устанавливаясь, исчезают где-то в недрах моего устройства, не показываясь в выходном каталоге. Так что когда я пытаюсь перенести выходную dll проекта куда-то в иное место, работать она отказывается. Можно ли как-то исправить это и либо заставить среду копировать необходимые пакеты в выходной каталог, либо же заставить приложение самостоятельно восстанавливать зависимости?

Comment: .NET Core работает по принципу проекта, который нужно собирать при помощью publish. Это можно сделать или через студию (пкм - Опубликовать) или командой `dotnet publish`. Так вы получите все необходимые файлы для запуска вашего проекта. Ну а если хотите что то экзотичное, то как вариант - [вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43837638/how-to-get-net-core-projects-to-copy-nuget-references-to-build-output).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Спасибо большое, помогло) Может, оформите как ответ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У .Net Core другие понятия "сборки", которые схожи по большей части с Web разработкой.
 Все Nuget пакеты при разработке он будет подцеплять скорей всего из директории `C:\Users\[YourUsername]\.nuget\packages`. А вот что бы сделать их в директории с проектом - надо сделать публикацию (ПКМ по проекту - Опубликовать; либо через консоль `dotnet publish`). Этим действием наш проект соберет все необходимые dll в нужную директорию.

Еще как вариант, в файле `.csproj` внутри `<PropertyGroup>` добавить следующее:

```
<CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
```

Включив данный параметр вы будете получать все dll в вашем каталоге после сборки.